# Can I manipulate a Shutterstock vector for a logo?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, logo, copyright, legal, licensing

I am designing a logo for a friend. I have the font and colors done. All I need is an icon for it. I found a vector on shutterstock that would be perfect. I took the vector and used it as a base and re-designed it so it's completely different from the original. Should i be worried about copyright and licencing.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**. You *should* be worried about copyrights and licensing.

Royalty-free stock imagery is typically set to **strictly forbid** use in a logo. Shutterstock specifically states that logo usage is **not** permissible on their site - *unless* you purchase the rights to the image which can cost considerably more than typical royalty-free costs. You will find this rather common among stock image providers.

**[Shutterstock's Help Center topic on logo/trademark usage](https://www.shutterstock.com/support/article/Using-Images-for-logos-and-trademarks?l=en_US&c=CustomerKB%3AImages&fs=Search&pn=1)**

And be aware, there is **no such thing** as *"edit the image by X amount and it's okay"*